# Infinite sigma-algebra is uncountable

Tags: measure-theory

The problem is so well-known, but I still do not understand some points in the following solution:

[image: Solution]

1. Why is every member $S$ of $\mathcal{S}$ a union of the sets $f(x)$ with $x\in S$ ?
2. What can we conclude if the partition is uncountable ?

I really appreciate any help from all of you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 1, for $S\in\mathcal{S}$, let $\hat{S}=\bigcup_{x\in S}f(x)$. Since $x\in f(x)$, we clearly have $S\subseteq\hat{S}$. In the other direction, note that $S\supseteq f(x)$ whenever $x\in S$ (since $S$ is an element of $\mathcal{S}$ containing $x$), so $\hat{S}\subseteq S$.

For 2, each element of the partition is an element of the $\sigma$-algebra.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)$ is a subset of $S$ $\forall x \in S$ by construction and contains $x$ so $\cup_{x \in S} f(x) = S$.

If the partition is uncountable then we have constructed an uncountable subset of the infinite set $\mathcal{A}$ so $\mathcal{A}$ must be uncountable too.